# How to prevent repeating content across all worlds

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using KML layers in Google Maps. And when I load a layer into a map, it shows up in every world as far as you keep horizontally scrolling. For layers with content on a quite small area that doesn't pose a problem, as the map will automatically zoom to show only the relevant content from the layer. But for layers that show markers across the whole world, having them repeat again on the next world, it looks like a bunch of gibberish.

Take for example this sample code from Google Maps, but with a layer of Holocene volcanoes instead of their layer provided by default. If you want to see all of them, you see more than all of them, and you have no reference for when you've come to the place where they are repeating the ones you've already looked at.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/eppptn2x/

Code:

```
var map;
var elevator;
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(10, 0)
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
var markers = [];

var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.volcano.si.edu/ge/GVPWorldVolcanoes.kml'
  });
  georssLayer.setMap(map);
```

How do I prevent this behavior? How do I make all layer content, and any markers, be limited to only one world?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question. Try entering a value for minZOom in mapOptions like this:

```
var myOptions = {
   zoom: 2,
   minZoom:2,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(10, 0)
};
```

Comment: No, not that you can't *see* the content from the next world, but that there isn't one. The difference is that if you were to pan to the next world horizontally, it should appear empty.

Comment: In google maps there is no concept of "one world" but only the concept of the map (map tiles) and zoom level. The representation of what map, or portion of the map, is always correlated to the desired magnification level and provides for the tiling of a series of elements all of the same SIZES (I 256 * 256) that constitute the map itself. In the event that your map is bigger than this size, and the magnification is such that it does not provide for additional elements less detailed google maps repeats the same element as in the case of two or more worlds we see side by side.

Comment: But how do go around that? I don't know if the "2nd world" itself can be chosen to never display, but I do know that the markers can be limited to one world, because I have once seen such an example. I just never learned how.

Comment: If you could show me the example I might have a look

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but may be it would be useful for someone.
To prevent repeating markers you can set `optimized` option to false

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!',
    optimized: false
  });
```

[You can find related topic here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29351026/3110505)